# Start Docker container using systemd socket activation?

Tags: docker, systemd

Can an individual Docker container, for example a web server, that exposes (listens on) a port be started using systemd's [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) feature?  The idea is to save resources by starting a container only when it is actually needed for the first time (and possibly stop it again when idle to save resources).

Note: This question is *not* about launching the Docker daemon itself using socket activation (which is already [supported](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/tree/master/contrib/init/systemd/socket-activation)), but about starting individual containers on demand.

Comment: I think it's possible, but difficult to find anything around.. I'm ready to write a blog post, but still can't figure out how to pass the socket from the host to the initiated docker. Maybe just mount it as a volume.. Here some reading: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activated-containers.html http://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html#activation

Comment: Is it a requirement to use systemd's socket activation feature?  How about using the Docker API to start and stop containers on demand?

Comment: Did you find a solution to shutdown the process when it is not used ?

Comment: Arka: I did not spend any time on that yet, as even the socket-activation is still missing. But I guess the server could try to track activity, and when it has been idle long enough trigger a shutdown.

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/03/docker-systemd-socket-activation/

Is this not what you want ?

Comment: Arka: Thanks for the link, which shows how systemd-socket-proxyd can be used to work around that Docker apparently does not support it directly. Ideally Docker would support it directly to avoid the need for workarounds such as systemd-socket-proxyd, but maybe this systems-socket-proxyd is as close as we can get for now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, you can't.

But, if you wanted to approach a solution, you would first need to run a tool like [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) or [geard](https://openshift.github.io/geard/) that runs each Docker container in a systemd service.

Even then, Docker's support for inheriting the socket has come and gone. I know geard is [working on stable support](https://github.com/openshift/geard/issues/50). CoreOS has published generalized support for [socket activation in Go](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/activation). Red Hat folks have also added in [related patches](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/golang/2014-May/001814.html) to Fedora's Docker packages that use Go's socket activation library and improve "foreground mode," a key component in making it work.

(I am the David Strauss from Lennart's [early article on socket activation of containers](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activated-containers.html), and this topic interests me a lot. I've emailed the author of the patch at Red Hat and contacted the geard team. I'll try to keep this answer updated.)

Comment: I read the article after the video actually :) I'm running CoreOS. But even if Docker is in systemd, I never saw one with socket activation. Thanks for your answer, a lot of links to all the discussions :) I have to do some tests, but I'm pretty sure it's doable. I'll keep you informed here :)

Comment: The key is being able to specify a socket listener in the container as inherited from systemd. I haven't seen a stable implementation of that yet.

Comment: It's coming :) https://github.com/coreos/rocket/issues/106 not with Docker though :)

Comment: @PierreOzoux Rocket's developers (the CoreOS team) have long been wonderful members of the systemd community and major contributors to the project.

Comment: Maybe you could mention that Podman (version >= 3.4.0) supports socket activation of containers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can with [Podman](https://podman.io/). For details, see the [Podman socket activation](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/socket_activation.md) tutorial.
Podman supports socket activation since version 3.4.0 (released Sep 2021).

(Docker does not yet support socket activation of containers so you would need to use Podman for this)

#### Example 1: mariadb

I wrote a small example demo of how to set up *socket activation* with **systemd**, **podman** and a **MariaDB** container:

https://github.com/eriksjolund/mariadb-podman-socket-activation

[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) supports socket activation since version **10.6** (released April 2021)

### Example 2: nginx

https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation

See also my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71188085/757777

Answer (score 2):

If it has to be using systemd, there was a blog post last month about that, [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/03/docker-systemd-socket-activation/) (haven't tried it myself yet).

If the choice of technology is not a hard constraint, you could just write a small proxy in your favorite programming language, and simply make a Docker API call to ensure the container is started. That's the way [snickers](https://github.com/michielbdejong/snickers-proxy/blob/46e7063dd70f45594c0832ea7c423c13b8edfbf7/spdy.js#L16) (my experimental nodejs proxy) does it.